# Thunderbird config for kernel patches - cannot find register key

Tags: thunderbird

I want to set up Thunderbird to be able to apply kernel patches. Kernel documentation (available [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/email-clients.txt)) says:

> Enable "preformat" mode: Set "editor.quotesPreformatted" to "true".

Unfortunately, under `Thunderbird 24.2.0` there isn't that key anymore. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Manually add key back in?

I believe you can try just adding that key back in via the "Config Editor". Just right click when you have the keys listed in the editor and select "New". Be sure to pick the type of "Boolean" and select "true" for its value.

[image: ss of editor]

[image: ss of key]

#### Force to HTML and then select preformatted in compose

According to @enedil's instructions in his answer, here's what I understand the menu to be in the US/English edition of Thunderbird.

*Edit* → *Account Settings* → *`<user's name>`* → *Composition and Addressing*. From here you'll want to check the box next to *"Compose message in HTML format"*.

[image: ss of prefs]

Once you've enabled HTML formatting you'll need to change the format in the *Compose* window to *Preformat*.

[image: ss of compose]

Comment: I wonder if it works. If it has disappear from Thunderbird, Mozilla has done it because it does probably nothing in recent versions of Thunderbird.

Comment: @enedil - Had that thought, the easiest way to confirm is to try it first, if it doesn't we can post a Q on either the thunderbird forums or in their issue tracker.

Comment: Ok, I'll try tomorrow (here, it's 1:20 AM).

Comment: @enedil - fair enough, pls let me know, I can assist with getting it moved up the chain if needed.

Comment: I found it. I must select HTML mails and select preformat from drop-down menu near subject while writting mail. Adding the register key didn't help.

Comment: @enedil - now that you described it I see what you're after. I've added the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I opened menu -> preferences -> account configuration -> `<my email account>` -> creating and selected "Twórz wiadomości w formacie HTML" what means "Create messages in HTML format".

When I'm creating a new mail, I must select "preformat" from drop-down menu near subject.